# Bootstrap Modal YouTube embed with while (extension errors)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I'm currently working on a website with YouTube embedded videos in Bootstrap modal. The problem is that YouTube embed is slowing down the website, because every embed is resulting in like 6 Chrome extension errors. This will result in like 100 errors and the website is going really slow.

Because it looks like every video is getting loaded, because they are in a while loop. Is there any other way to embed it? Without all these errors..

Can I make it better? I don't want all those errors. I tried object, but the videos are loading really slowly.

[image]

There is an image of the error.

---

I'm looping out images and when I click on them, it will embed out youtube videos.

```
        <div class="mosaic-block bar2">
            <div class="mosaic-overlay" >
                <div class="details">
                    <center><h4>'.$dos['namn'].'</h4></center><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><a href="#'.$dos['id'].'"><img src="uploads/'.$dos['bild'].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$dos['id'].'"></a></div>
        </div>


        <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="'.$dos['id'].'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="margin-top: 159px;/* float: left; */width: 800px;float: 0 auto;margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      <center><font color="grey">'.$dos['uppare'].'</font></center> <div class="content">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$dos['youtube'].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: I did add some code now!

Comment: @AndréSchild do you know?